# Cannot get populated EF object with linq from one to many relationship

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm having a problem getting data out of my db using EF and linq.  At a high level, I want to a fully populated object including the data from the many sides of my DB.

I have an AppUser table linked one-to-many to an AppUser_AppRole table, again, linked one to many to an AppRole table in our db.  I've double checked the FKs are there.

Now, I'm expecting to just be able to do something like this to get back what I want.

```
var currentAppUser = context.AppUsers
              .Where(x=>x.Id == currentAppUserId.Value)
              .Include(x=>x.AppRoles)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

I CAN type this out, and VS won't complain, but when I run it, I get the right user in currentAppRole, but nothing in AppRoles.  But when I run the following query, I get two rows, coming back.  So I know I'm doing something wrong with linq above.

```
select au.id, au.adusername, ar.id, ar.RoleName 
from appuser au join AppUser_AppRole auar on au.id = auar.AppUserID join approle ar on auar.AppRoleID = ar.ID 
where au.id = 4
```

Here's what the model looks like for these tables.
[image: model from vs]

I hope someone can help make sense of this for me.  Just as soon as I THINK I have a handle on EF\linq, I do what I did before, but I get different results (like this :<).  I'm frustrated by this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

PS  I've tried the other notation, the from...in... (lambda expression?) but I'm not sure that's working cause I don't know where\how to do the .Includes.

Comment: Can you post your AppUser entity and AppUser_Role entities? I'm guessing the way your relationships are defined are incorrect. It's possible that the first LINQ query can't include the AppRoles, but you're explicitly stating the join in your second query, which will give you the correct results.

Comment: I'm sorry, where do I go find that? Are you looking for something defined in xml or cs?  Thank you Drew for trying to help.

Comment: I was asking about the AppUser.cs file. It should have all of the properties defined for your AppUser entity.

Comment: I tried looking for it, even did a FindAll on everything, and there isn't one of those, isn't VS using the edmx to define that object from the table from the db?

Comment: Include is a method of DbSet. I've never seen Include after a Where method and am surprised it compiled. You should have AppUsers.Include(xx).Where....  This could very well be affecting the query execution. DOes changing that help? But that model is definitely convoluted with self-refernceing associations and the other relationships. also wrt Drew's suggestion, in VS, your EDMX should have classes below (attached to) it in solution explorer.

Comment: Thank you Julie for commenting.  I find it interesting that you say it shouldn't work but VS is clearly letting me do it, leads me to believe that different thing will happen if it's in different places...REALLY hard to predict and learn EF and linq if that's true. :< Frustrating.  But back to this prob, unfortunately it didn't help, same thing, nothing. :<

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm thinking of the C# like I would do something logical, start with the AppUser, cause that's the one side, and the var type I'm going to keep around, then since I'm going against a table in the db, put a where clause on it, then once you have THAT data, go include the AppRoles (and leave EF figure out the joining stuff).  Maybe I'm giving EF too much credit?

Comment: Your model is a mess. All these navigation properties "name" and "name1" are very confusing and probably the ones with "1" are all redundant. It looks like you've been trying to add and remove associations and add them again. Maybe you better remove these tables and add them again by updating the model. Then you can do `Incude("AppUser_AppRoles.AppUser")` or the lambda equivalent.

Comment: Thank you Gert for answering and trying.  Those other joins are required, there are auditing FKs to AppUser for CreatedById and LastUpdatedID.  Although they might look messy, they're required.  But you could be onto something, maybe it's something in the edmx? everywhere I look I've seeing how the initial .Include SHOULD be working.  I just don't know how\what to go look at to change?

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering.  My boss actually was able to figure it out.  The key was two fold, first getting the right navigation property (I thought I had it but obviously not :<) and then doing another select on that.  Here's the code that worked (sorry for formatting)), var currentAppUser = context.AppUsers
                        .Include(x => x.AppUser_AppRole2.Select(y => y.AppRole))
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentAppUserID);