# How do you get data across multiple tables with EF and linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a rather simple db structure, TableA joins to TableB joins to TableC, and I JUST want to get a linq statement to get the populated data objects.  Why is it sooooo hard?

I have something like this

```
TableA
ID (pk)

TableB
ID
TableAID (yes this is a fk to TableA)
TableCID (yes this is a fk to TableC)

TableC
ID (pk)
```

NOW, I'm trying to do a

```
var SomeVar = context.Include(t=>t.AnotherTable)
.Include(t => t.YetAnotherTable)
.Include(t => t.TableB)
.Include(t => t.TableC)
```

or maybe

```
.Include(t=>t.TableB.TableC)
```

But when I run these, NOTHING works, errors about navigation props don't exist.  How do I get this?  Any help would be appreciated please?!

Comment: Is it your intent to eager load these tables? or do you just want to select the data?

Comment: hhmm to be honest, both.  I know that doesn't really answer your question, I apologize.  I'm trying to get that data loaded into my objects on the client so I can do logic on them.  I was actually able to get what I wanted, it was the last line on a comment I wrote a while back found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572982/cannot-get-populated-ef-object-with-linq-from-one-to-many-relationship).  The secret was to include then do select the other 2nd table.  Just seemed a bit weird to me.  But I'm able to get it working.  PS  Thank you John for replying and so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a .Include() method that works on the db context itself, so I might be misunderstanding the question entirely.

It looks like you are thinking in terms of SQL JOIN statements which isn't how the EF works.  Let it take care of that for you.  Assuming that TableA, TableB, and TableC all have appropriate navigation properties then do something like this:

```
int myKey = 12345;
TableB myObject = context.TableBs.Where(b => b.ID == myKey).First();
```

At this point the variable "myObject" is of type TableB and has the properties: ID, TableA, TableB.  So if TableA had a property named "Name" you would access that as myObject.TableA.Name.  If you want to do this without a round-trip back to the server, you would write this:

```
TableB myObject = context.TableBs.Include(b => b.TableA).Where(b => b.ID == myKey).First();
```

This is "eager loading" but it is not necessary for getting data from a related table.

Comment: Thank you Moby for the reply.  My hiccup with this is the .First() when there is a possibility of multiples being returned.  Either way, I was able to find a solution (noted above).  Thank you again.